# Screen Resolution issue: Page not being fixed to larger screens

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing this website using Bootstrap. It's a one-page website for an exchange company. My issue is with the adjustment of the website to different screen sizes. As long as I test the website on 15" laptop screen, each module comes as a page but when the screen size increases to 1280 x 1024, it runs together.

Here is a link [Website](http://azurepublishing.com/fairdeals/test/Test/)

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue? Why is bootstrap not scaling the website for larger screen?

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot which describes your problem?

Comment: @herrh you can see the problem here http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//azurepublishing.com/fairdeals/test/Test/&w=1280&h=1024

I want the about section to be visible on scroll. It's running together with the front on screen size of 1280 x 1024.

Answer (score 0):

use font-weight: 500; for text which is rendering
and if cross-browser issue is there use -webkit-text-stroke:

Comment: The rows are not adjusting to the large screens. What has text to do with that?